# Scheme Greater than average function

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am making a program in Scheme (simply-scheme in Dr. Racket) that takes in a number of integers followed by the integer values. I need to be able to find the average of the list, which I have already got working and to be able to count the numbers greater than the average and display how many there are.

```
;;Function for the sum of list
(define (sum listlen) 
  (if
    (null? listlen)
    0
    (+ (car listlen) (sum (cdr listlen)))
  )
)






;;This is the part I am having trouble with
(let ((avg  (/ (apply + (cdr numbers)) (car numbers))))
  (count (lambda (x) (< x avg)) (cdr numbers)))
```

My function for finding the greater than average function is giving me an arity mismatch. it says 
"count: arity mismatch; 
the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
expected: 1
given: 2
arguments...:"

I'm sure it's something simple that I doing wrong if my greater than average function but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;;Function for the sum of list
(define (sum listlen) 
  (if
    (null? listlen)
    0
    (+ (car listlen) (sum (cdr listlen)))
  )
)
```

This is actually simply `(define (sum lst) (apply + lst))`.

Next,

```
(< x avg)
```

Should it actually be `(> x avg)` (to count numbers greater than the average)?

Finally, http://docs.racket-lang.org/manual@simply-scheme/index.html says for `count`:

> Return the number of letters in a word or number of words in a sentence.

Did you mean something like `(length (filter (lambda (x) (> x avg)) (cdr numbers)))`? (Can be done with `reduce` too, or named `let`, or whatever.)

Comment: That helped a ton. Thank you